# React state not reactive when triggered from outside library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive

React beginner here.

My code

```js
import Head from 'next/head';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Mousetrap from 'mousetrap';

export default function Home() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const triggerSomething = () => {
    console.log(count);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Mousetrap.bind(['ctrl+s', 'command+s'], e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      triggerSomething();
    });

    return () => {
      Mousetrap.unbind(['ctrl+s', 'command+s']);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>count: {count}</h1>

        <p className={styles.description}>
          <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>increment</button>
          <br />
          <br />
          <button onClick={triggerSomething}>triggerSomething</button>
        </p>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm having an issue when trying to trigger an event from `Mousetrap`. The `count` variable is not reactive when triggered from mousetrap but reactive when triggered from the button with `onClick`.

To replicate this bug you need to:

1. click the increment button once
2. click the triggerSomething button. The console should print out `1` (the current state of `count`)
3. push command+s or ctrl+s to trigger the same method. The console prints out `0` (the state of `count` when the component loaded). **That should print `1` (the current state).**

What am I doing wrong? What pattern should I use here?

UPDATE:
Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-dvnyeq?file=pages%2Findex.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you change the state, the component is re-rendered, i.e. the function is executed again, but the `useState` hook returns the updated counter this time. To use this updated value in your `MouseTrap`, you must create a new handler (and remove the old one). To achieve this, simply remove the dependency array of your `useEffect` call. It will then use the newly created `triggerSomething` function.

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Mousetrap from 'mousetrap';

export default function Home() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const triggerSomething = () => {
    console.log(count);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Mousetrap.bind(['ctrl+s', 'command+s'], e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      triggerSomething();
    });

    return () => {
      Mousetrap.unbind(['ctrl+s', 'command+s']);
    };
  }); // Notice that I removed the dependency array

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>count: {count}</h1>

        <p className={styles.description}>
          <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>increment</button>
          <br />
          <br />
          <button onClick={triggerSomething}>triggerSomething</button>
        </p>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Got it! It just seemed a bit wasteful to bind & unbind that event every time the component rendered.

Thank you!

Comment: As I stated. I'm a newbie with React.

Comment: or add [count] in dependency, I think React recommends adding dependencies if there are any dependent value than not using one. But I don't the way it needs to bind each time it re-renders.

Comment: @Rox The ``useEffect`` depends on the outer function ``triggerSomething`` which is recreated on every render. Hence there is no difference between including it in the dependencies or not.

Answer (score 3):

In the `triggerSomething` method you can use `setCount(count => count + 1)` and this should work.

The issue you have is when you don't put the `triggerSomething` as a dep in the `useEffect`, count would be the same as the initial state which is 0. but when passing a function counting on the previous value to `setCount`, you'll spare this issue.